# Why does this code of CSS not work without the >

Tags: css, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv7kfjrq/2/) I have an example of attempting to not apply a style on an object that is inside a div with the class .k-grid.

In the given example the following line of code does not work as I expected. 
As far as I understand CSS i'm saying: Every P object, that doesn't have the "fancy" class, and are not somewhere inside a div object with a .k-grid.

Since my given p object is inside a div with .k-grid, I dont expect it to turn green.. but it does.

```
<style>
form.editform div:not(.k-grid) p:not(.fancy) {
  color: green;
}
</style>
<form class="editform">
  <div>
    <div class="k-grid">
      <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
      <p class="fancy">
      <span class="notfancy">I am so very fancy!</span></p>
      <div class="fancy">I am NOT a paragraph.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I change `form.editform div:not(.k-grid) p:not(.fancy)` to `form.editform div:not(.k-grid)>p:not(.fancy)` it does properly exclude the p fancy from becoming green.

Can someone explain to me why a space does not work in removing the class from the object, while the >  does work? As well as explain what the difference is between "descendents" and "children".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descendents are children, and descendents of children (e.g. grandchildren, grand-grandchildren, etc). Your `<span>` is a descendant of `<form>`, but not a child of it.

In no case is `<div class="k-grid">` getting matched to `div:not(.k-grid)`.

Your selector is picking up `<form class="editform">` as its `form.editform`, its descendant (and incidentally a child) `<div>` for `div:not(.k-grid)`, and *its* descendant (more precisely, grandchild) `<p>` for `p:not(.fancy)`. You can check that this is what is going on by changing `<div>` to e.g. `<article>`, and seeing the CSS rule stop having an effect.

When you change the last part of your selector to child selector, `<p>` cannot match because it is a grandchild of `<div>`.